# Responsive design with YAML and very small screen width

Tags: css, responsive-design, yaml-css

My responsive design with YAML works pretty good. On screens with very small width however, the YAML grids get very small and it would make more sense to display the right grid below the left one rather than left/right. http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//www.kine-stammheim.ch/kontakt.php&w=320&h=568&a=37&s=1&p=1

Somehow this works pretty good with the YAML examples. http://www.yaml.de/demos/flexible-grid.html
But why not on my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linearize-level-1 etc. does the job: http://www.yaml.de/docs/index.html#yaml-columns